# Date function support for multiple distributions

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am looking for some help related to writing a script which can be executed on OS such as ubuntu, amazon-linux and OSX.

The following is a simple script which calculates number of days between two dates.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=$(gdate '+%Y-%m-%d')

first_date=$(gdate -d "$current_date" "+%s")
second_date=$(gdate -d "${1}" "+%s")

case "$3" in
    "--seconds" | "-s") period=1
    ;;
    "--minutes" | "-m") period=60;;
    "--hours" | "-h") period=$((60*60));;
    "--days" | "-d" | "") period=$((60*60*24));;
esac

datediff=$(( ($first_date - $second_date)/($period) ))
```

The issue with the above is that it can only run on OSX where gdate (GNU date) is available. **Could someone suggest a solution that performs the same procedure and can be executed on different systems?**

Thanks

Comment: `gdate` is not available by default even on OS X.  But `date` is available everywhere.  Have you tried using `date`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct but date on OSX behaves completely different. So in short OSX date != Linux/ubuntu date

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution that satisfies me. So I am checking which distribution is being used and based on that I can select the correct tool: `gdate` on OS X, `date` otherwise.

```
check_package() {
  package_name=${1}
  check_type=$(which ${package_name})
  if [[ -z "${check_type}" ]] ;
  then
    echo "Install the required ${package_name} which isn't installed!"
    echo "Ensure ${package_name} is in your $PATH"
    exit 2
  fi
}
# Usage calculate_date_diff package_name date -d/-h/-m/-s
calculate_date_diff() {
  current_date=$(${1} '+%Y-%m-%d')
  first_date=$(${1} -d "$current_date" "+%s")
  second_date=$(${1} -d "${2}" "+%s")

  case "${3}" in
    "--seconds" | "-s") period=1;;
    "--minutes" | "-m") period=60;;
    "--hours" | "-h") period=$((60*60));;
    "--days" | "-d" | "") period=$((60*60*24));;
  esac

  datediff=$(( (${first_date} - ${second_date})/(${period}) ))
  echo ${datediff}
}

# Format of date: yyyy-mm-dd
DATE_IN_PAST=${1}

# Detect the platform (similar to $OSTYPE)
OS="$(uname)"
case ${OS} in
  'Darwin') 
    check_package "gdate" && calculate_date_diff "gdate" ${DATE_IN_PAST} -d
    ;;
  'Linux')
    check_package "date" && calculate_date_diff "date" ${DATE_IN_PAST} -d
    ;;
  'FreeBSD')
    check_package "date" && calculate_date_diff "date" ${DATE_IN_PAST} -d
    ;;
  'SunOS')
    check_package "date" && calculate_date_diff "date" ${DATE_IN_PAST} -d
    ;;
  *) ;;
esac
```

[Github file with the solution](https://github.com/marcincuber/aws_access_keys/blob/master/date.sh)

Comment: If you are going to post an answer, put the code in the answer itself, rather than just a link to an external site.